# How to interpret a random intercept?

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

Suppose we have a hierarchical model regression model (pupils nested in schools) with random intercept for schools. We run a model with data covering a particular period, and observe the variance of the random intercept.

Now we run the same model (same model formulation: ie, same outcome and predictors etc) on a dataset consisting of the same schools, but for different pupils at a different time.

Now, suppose also that the incidence of the model outcome is significantly different in the two models, but the fixed effects and the the variance of the random intercept is the same (or very similar): what can we conclude from this ? Is it valid to say that whatever has happened to change the outcome has affected all the schools uniformly ?

**Update**

The outcome of my model is the incidence of bullying. I wondered if maybe the incidence changed because of something that does not affect individual schools differently, such as the local education authority having an awareness/monitoring/policing/funding policy that affected all schools the same - in that case, wouldn't the random intercept be unchanged ?

Comment: In what way is the model significantly different?

Comment: Since you say "incidence" I am assuming you ran a logistic mixed effect model.

If the fixed effects are the same and the variance of the random effects are the same, how is the incidence so different?

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you. When I mentioned incidence I was just talking about the number of cases divided by the number of pupils. Also, The fixed effects (and random effects) estimate have changed a bit, but their confidence intervals almost cover each other, so that's why I say they are the same. I know there might be an issue of power to detect a change, but the sample size is very large so I didn't think that would be a problem. I am really just focusing here on what it means for the random intercept to be unchanged...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variances of the random intercepts are similar, it just means that the *spread* of the schools is roughly the same. If you want to look at whether or not the fixed effects affected the schools differently between times 1 and 2, I think you need to look at the interaction between time and the fixed effects. This would mean combining the two data sets and adding a variable to distinguish them.

Alternatively, if you just want to see if the incidence changed by similar amounts across schools, you could look at the differences in incidence in a box plot or some similar plot and you could find the mean, sd, maximum difference and so on.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you clarify what you mean by "the spread of the schools" and what the interpretation of that is ? If the outcome has changed, then is it correct to say that the schools have been affected uniformly (because the variance of the intercept has not changed) perhaps due to some change in teaching practice that all schools have adopted) ? Or is it better to say that the schools haven't been affected at all ?

Comment: The random intercept is an intercept for each school (in effect). Thus, the variance of the random intercept is a measure of how much the schools vary. 

To see if the schools have changed uniformly, see my previous comment. Clearly, they have been affected if the incidence changes.

Comment: Just another point - I won't have time to run any more models, so I'm really just looking for a way to interpret what I have found from the models I have run. Of course, if I have run the wrong models, that's also OK - I will just report this to my teacher - I am self studying statistics in the holidays and my teacher is helping to guide me. He gave me this data to make a report on, so I just have to interpret what I found. If I did it wrong, it's OK - I guess I can also say that :)